# IP для подключения к сокету

Tags: java

Я через android могу подключится к серверу только через 192.168.0.102, а через айпи который выдаёт сайт 2ip.ru, не выходит. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`192.168.0.102` - это ip в локальной сети.

2ip.ru выдаёт ваш внешний ip за NAT'ом. К нему вы не сможете подключиться, пока порт не пробросите.

Comment: Где взять айпи, что бы я мог сидеть на сервере например с мобильного?

Comment: У вас ip внешний статический?

Comment: Нет, динамический.

Comment: @Евгений вам на роутере пробросить порт нужно.

Comment: А в клиенте какой IP указать, локальный или внешний?

Comment: @Евгений если в локальной сети тестируете, то локальный. Если хотите из вне работать, то внешний  + пробросить порт на роутере.